# How can I capture a password typed on screen and pass to Python script ?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script I am running and one of the commands asks for a passcode to be inputted by the user. 
I want to capture (save) that passcode and pass it back to the script for later use.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module.

```
import getpass
pw = getpass.getpass() # prompts user for password
```

`pw` is now a string that contains the password entered by the user.

Comment: This is great! Thanks both of you. But my questions is slightly different - Lets say the command I run generates a certificate and as a part of that it asks for a passcode. I enter it twice for confirmation. I am hoping to capture that passcode and return it back to the script. The solutions above using getpass() would ask me for a 3rd time to re-enter the passcode which I can capture and return back. And thats fine. But I was hoping if there was a way to capture the passcode in the first 2 attempts of generating the certificate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pass it back to the script - I'd need some more context. I don't see any issue with passing back the variable `pw`.

Comment: One of the command is an openssl shell command to generate certificates
    command = 'openssl <generate cert command options>'
    run_system_command(command)  -->  This prompts user for password (twice for verification).  I want to save this passcode and return it back to the script for later use in the script.  By adding a call to getpass(), I can prompt the user for the 3rd time to enter the same passcode and save it like you mentioned and return it for later use. But I do not have a way to verify this passcode matches the passcode entered on the openssl command.

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure if its possible to do that then. The only way I see it happening is if you can somehow send the password to the system command. Then, you could ask twice at the beginning, save that as the password and pass that to the system command.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Dont think I can/want to send a password to the openssl command that prompts the user for a new password.

Answer (score 0):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from getpass import getpass

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="arg parser hidden password input.")
    parser.add_argument('-sp', '--secure_password', action='store_true', dest='password', 
                        help='hidden password prompt')
    args=parser.parse_args()

    if args.password:
        password = getpass()

    print(password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```